# Action Required: Your app is not compliant with Google Play Policies, Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ut2f.png)

**Issue found:** Invalid Encryption Declaration on your Data safety form
We’ve detected discrepancies between how your app collects and shares user data and what was declared in your app’s Data safety form. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

You have declared that user data is encrypted in transit in your app’s Data safety form and we’ve detected unencrypted network traffic that may carry user data off device.

**Issue details**

We found an issue in the following area(s):

SPLIT_BUNDLE 64: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: "http://atracking-auto.astrodsp.com"

what we can do, how to sole this

Comment: Can you post all your used libraries?

Answer (score 0):

If your app's functionality requires that you use the `cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` setting, then you have two options:

1. Find the SDK (probably an ad network) doing that and remove it.
2. Change our data safety form so it says you don't encrypt data in transit.